# Validar edad con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola a todos tengo un script que me permite calcular la edad automáticamente, como puedo realizar una validación que le indique al usuario por medio de un alert que no esta autorizado , si este tiene una edad de 65 años.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  $('#fecha_nac').on('change', function(){
  $('#edad').val(Calcular_Edad());
});


function Calcular_Edad()
{
  var fecha_seleccionada = $('#fecha_nac').val();
  var fecha_nacimiento = new Date(fecha_seleccionada);
  var fecha_Actual = new Date();
  var edad = (parseInt((fecha_Actual - fecha_nacimiento) / (1000*60*60*24*365)));
  return edad;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pues antes del return, hacer la condición para que entonces te muestre el alert:

```
if(edad == 65){
        alert('No autorizado');
        edad = 'No autorizado';
    }
```

Y depende donde estés mostrando la edad puedes cambiarle el valor a la variable edad

Comment: Gracias, funciono perfectamente

Comment: @Marcos Comprendido y realizada la operación, ya valore la respuesta se me había pasado por alto.